# Paperclip :style depending on model (has_many polymorphic images)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have set up my models to use a polymorphic Image model. This is working fine, however I am wondering if it is possible to change the :styles setting for each model. Found some examples using STI (Model < Image) However this is not an option for me, because I am using a has_many relation.

Art

```
has_many :images, :as => :imageable
```

Image

```
belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :thumb => "150x150>", :normal => "492x600>"}
                         #Change this setting depending on model
```

### UPDATE

I tried starting up a debugger inside the Proc method. Only fields related to the attached file is populated:

```
run'irb(Image):006:0> a.instance => #<Image id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, imageable_id: nil, imageable_type: nil, file_file_name: "IMG_9834.JPG", file_content_type: "image/jpeg", file_file_size: 151326, file_updated_at: "2010-10-30 08:40:23">
```

This is the object from ImageController#create

```
ImageController#create
@image => #<Image id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, imageable_id: 83, imageable_type: "Art", file_file_name: "IMG_9834.JPG", file_content_type: "image/jpeg", file_file_size: 151326, file_updated_at: "2010-10-30 08:32:49">
```

I am using paperclip (2.3.5) and Rails 3.0.1. No matter what I do the a.instance object is the image with only the fields related to the attachment populated. Any ideas?

### UPDATE2

After reading a lot on the Paperclip forum I don't believe it's possible to access the instance before it has been saved. You can onlye see the Paperclip stuff and that's it.

I got around this problem by presaving the image from the Image controller with a before filter - without the attachment

```
  before_filter :presave_image, :only => :create

  ...

  private

  def presave_image
    if @image.id.nil? # Save if new record / Arts controller sets @image
      @image = Image.new(:imageable_type => params[:image][:imageable_type], :imageable_id => params[:image][:imageable_id])
      @image.save(:validate => false)
      @image.file = params[:file] # Set to params[:image][:file] if you edit an image.
    end
  end
```

Comment: perhaps it is really due to the polymorphic association - or something similar, at least you have now a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am *really* late to the party here, but I wanted to clarify something about accessing model data for anyone else that happens on to this thread. I just faced this issue while using Paperclip to apply watermarks based on data from the model, and got it working after a lot of investigation.

You said:

> After reading a lot on the Paperclip forum I don't believe it's possible to access the instance before it has been saved. You can only see the Paperclip stuff and that's it.

In fact, you can see the model data *if it's been set in the object before your attachment is assigned*!

Your paperclip processors and whatnot are invoked when the attachment in your model is assigned. If you rely on mass assignment (or not, actually), as soon as the attachment is assigned a value, paperclip does its thing.

Here's how I solved the problem:

In my model with the attachment (Photo), I made all the attributes EXCEPT the attachment `attr_accessible`, thereby keeping the attachment from being assigned during mass assignment.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attribution, :latitude, :longitude, :activity_id, :seq_no, :approved, :caption

  has_attached_file :picture, ...
  ...
end
```

In my controller's create method (for example) I pulled out the `picture` from the `params`, and then created the object. (It's probably not necessary to *remove* the picture from `params`, since the `attr_accessible` statement should prevent `picture` from being assgined, but it doesn't hurt). *Then* I assign the `picture` attribute, *after* all the other attributes of the photo object have been setup.

```
def create
  picture = params[:photo].delete(:picture)
  @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
  @photo.picture = picture

  @photo.save
  ...
end
```

In my case, one of the styles for picture calls for applying a watermark, which is the text string held in the `attribution` attribute. Before I made these code changes, the attribution string was never applied, and in the watermark code, `attachment.instance.attribution` was always `nil`. The changes summarized here made the entire model available inside the paperclip processors. **The key is to assign your attachment attribute *last*.**

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please help me. I can see that you know what you talking about. I'm messing with paperclip. How can i create object with attachment field without attachment itself?

Answer (score 6):

I found the workaround to pickup styles on create.
The key is to implement `before_post_process` and `after_save` hooks.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  DEFAULT_STYLES = {
    medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>"
  }

  has_attached_file :file, styles: ->(file){ file.instance.styles }


  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  # Workaround to pickup styles from imageable model
  # paperclip starts processing before all attributes are in the model
  # so we start processing after saving

  before_post_process ->{
    !@file_reprocessed.nil?
  }

  after_save ->{
    if !@file_reprocessed && (file_updated_at_changed? || imageable_type_changed?)
      @file_reprocessed = true
      file.reprocess!
    end
  }


  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  def styles
    if imageable_class.respond_to?(:image_styles)
      imageable_class.image_styles
    end || DEFAULT_STYLES
  end

  def imageable_class
    imageable_type.constantize if imageable_type.present?
  end


end
```

So you have to define image_styles class method in imageable_class
In my case it was

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.image_styles
    {
      large: "570x380#",
      thumb: "50x70#",
      medium: "300x200#"
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: Worked for me. The trick is in before_post_process and after_save hooks.

Answer (score 3):

the `:styles` property takes a `Proc` as argument, so you can do all kinds of fancy stuff :)

```
class Image < AR::Base
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => Proc.new { |a| a.instance.file_styles }

  def file_styles; { :thumb => "150x150>", :normal => "492x600>" } end
end

class Didum < Image
  def file_styles; { :thumb => "50x50>", :normal => "492x600>" } end
end
```

Note - the above code should work, but honestly I have no setup to verify it, but looks like the `Paperclip::Attachment#styles` does `call` if it responds to it, see http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Attachment:styles

**UPDATE** the object passed into the `Proc` is not the instance, but the `Paperclip::Attachment`, but the instance is accessible through `instance` on the attachment

PS: And I've seen this in some other places, but can't remember where...

Comment: Same problem as Adam's example. The model will crash with a nil error when the model is a new unsaved record. Works fine with saved record though.

Comment: do you have an info about where the error happens exactly, i.e. in the Proc or where?

Comment: added `Proc.new { |a| Rails.logger.error(a.instance.inspect); { ... } }` in one of my projects (rails 3.0.0, paperclip 2.3.4) and it correctly returned my instance - so... it really might boil down to the version used or something similar...

Answer (score 2):

I've also met with the same problem and after searching for an elegant solution I didn't found anything "really" useful. So, here's my simple solution which seems alright for now; (tho I'm not sure if it has any downsides for the moment)

In model;

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true

  has_attached_file :attachment,  path: ":rails_root/#{path}/assets/images/:style/:filename",
                                  url: '/assets/images/:style/:filename',
                                  styles: -> (a) { a.instance.send(:styles) }
private
  def styles
    raise 'Undefined assetable.' unless assetable

    if assetable.class == Photo
      { small: 'x40', medium: '120x', large: '300x' }
    elsif assetable.class == Avatar
      { small: 'x40', medium: '120x', large: '300x' }
    else
      raise "Styles for #{assetable.class} is not defined."
    end
  end
end
```

In controller;

```
@photo = Photo.new
@photo.build_image(assetable: @photo, attachment: params[:photo][:image_attributes][:attachment])
@photo.save
```

Comment: Thanks, it just helped me tackled a rather annoying problem. This solution works wonderfully and I like its simplicity. I also made [some amendments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34368255/4499464) for it to work better in my project.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base  

  belongs_to :banner_categoria
  validates :banner_categoria_id ,{:presence =>{:message => "não informada"}} 

  has_attached_file :arquivo
  after_initialize :init_attachment




  def init_attachment
    self.class.has_attached_file :arquivo,
      :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      :styles => hash = {
      :banner => {
        :geometry => "#{self.banner_categoria.largura}x#{self.banner_categoria.altura}>",
        :quality => 80
      },
      :thumb => "100x100#"
    }
  end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

I liked MarkGranoff's answer but I came up with a much simpler implementation that does the trick for me and seems more maintainable.

```
#create new and instantiate the fields you need ( or all except the attachment )
@photo = Photo.new(:attribution => params[:photo][:attribution],
                   :latitude => params[:photo][:latitude ])

#then just assign all params as normal
@photo = Photo.assign_attributes(params[:node])
```

The second statement assigns the attachment so the processor is fired, and since you've already assigned :attribution and :latitude, their values will be available in the processor via the attachment.instance method.

Thanks everyone here for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

After couple of hours of digging into source code of both, `ActiveRecord` and `Paperclip`, I think there's a solution involving a bit of monkey-patching hackery.

I haven't thoroughly tested it but seems to work for my humble needs.

Below is my `config/initializers/activerecord_associations_patch.rb`:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class HasManyAssociation

      def build_record(attributes)
        if options[:as] && owner
          # Unicorns
          reflection.build_association({}) do |record|
            set_owner_attributes(record)
            unless foreign_key_for?(record)
              record.public_send "#{options[:as]}=", owner
            end
            initialize_attributes(record)
            record.assign_attributes(attributes)
          end
        else
          # Classic Rails way
          reflection.build_association(attributes) do |record|
            initialize_attributes(record)
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Since `reflection` doesn't know our `@owner`, it first assigns the `attributes` which triggers call to `record.#{instance}=` (i.e. `Image#file=`), which in turn forwards it to `#assign` and performs `post_processing` hook, which in the end leads to calling `styles` `Proc` provided in `has_attached_file` without polymorphic `imageable` being set. huh…

I rewrote the method to build the record first and assign provided attributes later.
Also, it accounts for `record#new_record?` in `foreign_key_for?` check.

In this way `attributes` are assigned once the record has been properly setup. At least i think so ;)

Cleaner solutions and constructive comments are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar question when dealing with dynamic behavioral changes on my models. Playing around with irb, I found out that this works:

```
module Foo
   attr_accessor :bar
end
class Bar
   extends Foo
end
bar.bar = 'test' # 'test'
bar.bar # 'test'
# also works for instances of Bar!
```

So i would create an attribute called image_style that could be changed to whatever module you want to add, by using this code on Image initialization:

```
  def after_initialize
    if self.image_style?
       extend Object.const_get(image_style)
    else
       extend DefaultImageStyle
    end
  end
```

I just wonder if this works with paperclip since the after_initialize method may be called after paperclip does it's magic.. Worth a try though!

Comment: I forgot to mention: The module would have the has_attached_file directive, along with the styles you want!

Comment: hmmm I don't know how to use that in my case. Looks fancy though :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Paperclip source for Attachment it looks like the `styles` hash can take an object that responds to `call` so you may be able to do something like:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => lambda {|attachment| attachment.instance.imageable_type.constantize.image_styles }
end
```

Then in any model that has many images:

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable

  def self.image_styles
    { :thumb => "150x150>", :normal => "492x600>" }
  end
end
```

**Edit**: Looks like someone else beat me to it :P.

Comment: Apparently instance_read is for attributes related to the image itself because it prepends the attachment name. The edits I have made should work.

Answer (score -2):

have the same problem in a production/staging server...BUT not in my local environment. I use same rails/paperclip versions in all servers (2.3.2 and 2.2.6)